# vichuploader cannot update file in production

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using vichuploader for storing avatars. Eveyrhing is working fine on my local server but during file update in production server throw such error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "Unable to create the "kernel.root_dir/../image/avatar/4" directory" at /home/xxx/xxxx.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php line 110 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException(code: 0): Unable to create the \"kernel.root_dir/../image/avatar/4\" directory at /home/xxx/xxx.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php:110)"} []
```

I use symfony 3 on OVH shared hosting, does anyone have idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have not permission to create files in directory /image/avatar